# ng-click is not calling my function inside controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic and angular.js. I'm trying to call a function `sayHello()` which is written in controller. Here's how I wrote. 
In html,

```
<button class="button button-large"><i class="icon ion-android-send" style="color:blue" ng-click="sayHello()"></i></button>
```

In controllers.js,

```
.controller('CommentCtrl',function($rootScope, $scope, $state, CommentService){
     $scope.sayHello = function(){
         alert('hello');
     }
})
```

In app,

```
.state('app.comment',
    {
      url:'/comment',
      views:{
        'menuContent':{
          templateUrl:'templates/comment.html',
          controller:'CommentCtrl'
         }
    }
});
```

I'm stilling finding my mistake spending hours but I'm still facing that issue. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<button class="button button-large" ng-click="sayHello()"><i class="icon ion-android-send" style="color:blue"></i></button>
```

The ng-click should be in the button, not the icon.

Comment: Wow.., Wow.., of cuz.., I didn't notice that. Plus, I'm not familiar with html, css and js stuffs. Thank you so much @Gene

Comment: @CristyYG You're welcome. It happens. Please accept this as the answer if it solved your question. Thanks!

Comment: I can only accept the answer in next 5mins as the site's policy. Please wait. :D